# R: How can I get a vector of dates from a vector of date + time strings?

Tags: r

I have a character vector of dates:

```
my.date.time.strings <- c("11/22/2014 15:48", "10/26/2014 10:44", "10/11/2014 20:18", "11/12/2014 13:58", "10/1/2014 20:59", "10/12/2014 11:13", "10/14/2014 15:54", "11/4/2014 8:36", "10/24/2014 17:22", "10/19/2014 16:51")
```

I want to extract the dates and cast them to R's date type.

I wrote a function to call with `sapply`:

```
getDate <- function(myDateTime) {
  ##This should get the date component of each string
  date = unlist(strsplit(as.character(myDateTime), " ", fixed = TRUE))[1]

  ##This should cast it
  date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")

  return(date)
}
```

But this call

```
print(my.dates <- sapply(my.date.time.strings, getDate))
```

Returns results I can't make sense of:

```
[1] 16396 16369 16354 16386 16344 16355 16357 16378 16367 16362
```

What should I be doing to get these dates extracted and formatted?

EDIT: As several commenters (and the accepted answer) suggest it's as simple as,

```
my.dates <- as.Date(my.date.time.strings, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Why not just `as.Date(my.date.time.strings, "%m/%d/%Y")`?

Comment: Please check `?strptime`.

Comment: @Thalecress Your numeric results can be converted back to `date` by `as.Date(my.dates, origin='1970-01-01')`, but it is better to use AnandaMahto's suggestion instead of a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function works, but it is just giving you the numeric representation of the date. Convert it using `as.Date` and specify `origin = "1970-01-01"`:

```
print(my.dates <- as.Date(sapply(
  my.date.time.strings, getDate), origin = "1970-01-01"))
# 11/22/2014 15:48 10/26/2014 10:44 10/11/2014 20:18 11/12/2014 13:58 
#     "2014-11-22"     "2014-10-26"     "2014-10-11"     "2014-11-12" 
#  10/1/2014 20:59 10/12/2014 11:13 10/14/2014 15:54   11/4/2014 8:36 
#     "2014-10-01"     "2014-10-12"     "2014-10-14"     "2014-11-04" 
# 10/24/2014 17:22 10/19/2014 16:51 
#     "2014-10-24"     "2014-10-19"
```

Of course, this is overkill, since you can just directly use `as.Date`:

```
as.Date(my.date.time.strings, "%m/%d/%Y")
#  [1] "2014-11-22" "2014-10-26" "2014-10-11" "2014-11-12" "2014-10-01"
#  [6] "2014-10-12" "2014-10-14" "2014-11-04" "2014-10-24" "2014-10-19"
```